# Inconsistent buttons in review queue

Tags: bug, review

Seeing we are [looking at changes to the review queue](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/experiment-more-aggressive-review-queue-indicator), I thought I'd ask about an issue that has bugged me for years.

In *some* of the queues (and don't ask which, because despite using the site for nearly seven years I still am surprised when it is not there) there is a button to vote for deletion, and in other queues there is not, so the only option is to flag the post for moderator attention.

This reminds me of one of those lab experiments where sinister white coats disorient unwitting subjects to further their insidious ends.

I assume that there is some well thought out rationale behind this, but for the life of me I cannot divine it, and it is annoying as all get out to go into the queue, find a post that [definitely should be deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/222245) only then to discover, *nope: no delete button for you!*

So, I have to flag it for a mod's attention when, clearly, it doesn't deserve flagging, or a mod's time. I have the power to vote to delete; why I am being stymied?

Comment: You are probably aware, but you can generally hit the little link button on the right and have your way with the unadulterated post...

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, but that takes you out of the review queues, which seems sort of pointless (from a UX perspective, anyway).

Comment: As you are probably aware, many browsers have a Ctrl+click feature that opens a link in a new tab (and Shift+click, which opens in a new window, and corresponding options on the right-click menu).

Comment: @G-man Yep, that's a workaround for a broken UI.

Comment: While we’re on the subject, what’s the deal with the Low Quality Posts review queue not allowing you to *vote* on the post?  When you see a wrong answer, the correct action is “Looks OK” + downvote. And you have to open it in a new tab to do that, too.

Comment: @G-Man I'd forgotten about that: it's in the same category of brokeness, IMO.

Comment: [status-declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228738/307535) from a few years ago

Comment: @JeffSchaller Great: broken, but broken *by design*.