# Red notification when review queue is too long

Tags: bug, review, user-interface, top-bar

I've see a small bug, I've reviewed 20 vote close today, and though I can't consult the vote close queue, I still have the red notification icon in review queue while I can't consult it, I think it shouldn't advertise you a queue you can't review when it's too long.
[image: Notification example]

Comment: The notification UI is [irredeemably broken](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4721/6761).